# I would like to keep multiple TextField to hold values

Tags: flutter

I am developing a fill-in-the-blanks quiz app.
Each quiz contains 5 sentences and they are arranged by PageView. The sentences are retrieved from a List.
Each sentence is a TextWithBlanks class and they have several BlankWord class (which are TextField).

```
class TextWithBlanks extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  static final regex = RegExp("(?={)|(?<=})");
  List correctList = [];

  TextWithBlanks({Key? key, required this.text, required this.correctList})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextWithBlanks> createState() => _TextWithBlanksState();
}

class _TextWithBlanksState extends State<TextWithBlanks> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final split = widget.text.split(TextWithBlanks.regex);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, right: 30.0, left: 30.0),
      child: Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 3.0),
          children: <InlineSpan>[
            for (String text in split)
              text.startsWith('{')
                  ? WidgetSpan(
                      child: blankWord(text.substring(1, text.length - 1),
                          widget.correctList),
                    )
                  : TextSpan(text: text),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class blankWord extends StatefulWidget {
  final String answer;
  int answerLength = 0;
  double answerWidth = 0.0;
  String answerHint = "";
  List correctList;
  String value = "";
  bool answerBool = false;

  blankWord(this.answer, this.correctList, {Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    answerLength = answer.length;
    answerWidth = answerLength * 15.0;
    answerHint = answer;
  }

  @override
  State<blankWord> createState() => _blankWordState();
}

class _blankWordState extends State<blankWord> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.answerWidth,
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: null,
        cursorColor: Colors.grey,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        autofocus: false,
        maxLength: widget.answerLength + 5,
        onChanged: (enterWord) {
          widget.value = enterWord;
          if (enterWord == widget.answer) {
            if (widget.answerBool == false) {
              widget.answerBool = true;
              widget.correctList.add(widget.answer);
            }
          } else {
            if (widget.answerBool == true) {
              widget.answerBool = false;
              widget.correctList.remove(widget.answer);
            }
          }
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          counterText: "",
          hintText: widget.answerHint,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I enter text in one TextWithBlank BlankWord and then enter text in another TextWithBlank BlankWord, what I entered before disappears.
I want to keep the value in the BlankWord (TextField) of each TextWithBlank. What is the best way to do this?
Thank you.

TextWithBlank is included in the QuizText class.

```
class PlayGame extends StatefulWidget {
  final List document;
  List correctList = [];
  PlayGame({Key? key, required this.document}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayGame> createState() => _PlayGameState();
}

class _PlayGameState extends State<PlayGame> {
  int quizNum = 0;
  int quizCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Center(
          child: Text(
            "$quizCount/5",
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          if (quizCount == 5)
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Result(),
                  ),
                );
                print(widget.correctList.length);
              },
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    "採点する",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward,
                    size: 20,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          else
            const SizedBox.shrink()
        ],
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: PageView(
        onPageChanged: (counter) {
          setState(
            () {
              quizCount = counter + 1;
            },
          );
        },
        children: [
          QuizText(widget: widget, quizNum: 0),
          QuizText(widget: widget, quizNum: 1),
          QuizText(widget: widget, quizNum: 2),
          QuizText(widget: widget, quizNum: 3),
          QuizText(widget: widget, quizNum: 4)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizText extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuizText({
    Key? key,
    required this.widget,
    required this.quizNum,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final PlayGame widget;
  final int quizNum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Card(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                child: TextWithBlanks(
                    text: widget.document[quizNum],
                    correctList: widget.correctList),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include how you are using `TextWithBlanks`

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: TextWithBlank is included in the QuizText class. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the widget is not used, it disposes from widget tree and value lost. You can use state-management property. For now I am using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to preserve the widget .

Changes will be here

```dart
class _TextWithBlanksState extends State<TextWithBlanks>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    final split = widget.text.split(TextWithBlanks.regex);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, right: 30.0, left: 30.0),
      child: Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, height: 3.0),
          children: <InlineSpan>[
            for (String text in split)
              WidgetSpan(
                child: blankWord(
                  text.substring(1, text.length - 1),
                  widget.correctList,
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```